# Delete httpOnly cookies - Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, cookies

Is it possible to delete browser cookies that are set as `HttpOnly:true`?

My login endpoint is simple like this:

```
  async login(@Ip() ipAddress, @Request() req, @Res() res: Response) {
      const auth = await this.basicAuthService.login(req.user, ipAddress);
      const cookieOptions = setTokenCookie();
      res.cookie('token', auth.token,  { httpOnly: true, expires: myDate()});
      res.cookie('refreshToken', auth.refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, expires: myDate()});
      res.send(auth);
    }
```

Works perfect, I call the /login endpoint in my react front end with axios

```
const res = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/authentication/login`, { email, password }, { withCredentials: true });
```

So far, so good, cookies are set. But I want to delete those cookies when I log out, since they are `HttpOnly:true` I can't delete them on frontend. I have tried with `res.clearCookie()` method but they are still in the browser.

```
  async logout(@Request() req, @Res() res: Response) {
      res.clearCookie('refreshToken' ,{ domain: 'localhost', path: '/', expires: new Date(0) });
      res.clearCookie('token', { domain: 'localhost', path: '/', expires: new Date(0) });
      console.log('cookies deleted');
      res.send();
    }
```

I thought this wasn't possible and then, I tried to login in my Facebook account and I was able to see some `HttpOnly:true` cookies which are deleted when logout.

Comment: In HTTP if you set a cookie with an empty value, or past expiry date, browsers will delete it. If you're not seeing that, there's likely something else wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I have read this on other posts. What else can be happening?

Comment: Setting a cookie with the same name and a Date(0) should suffice. res.cookie('token', '', { expires: new Date(0) })

Comment: One possibility is that you have multiple things making requests to your server, there's a race condition and you immediately get a new cookie. Or: one of your parameters like domain does not match.

Comment: Or whatever server-side cookie library you use does not do what you think it does with clearCookie.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is almost 2 years old but was the first link I found when trying to fix the same issue.

From the [Express 4.x - API Reference](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.clearCookie)

> Web browsers and other compliant clients will only clear the cookie if the given options is identical to those given to res.cookie(), excluding expires and maxAge.

To properly delete an `httpOnly` cookie you must pass that as an option in the second parameter as such

```
res.clearCookie('token', { httpOnly: true });
```

I believe the same applies to `sameSite`, `secure` etc