# Unable to delete a cookie that is HttpOnly using an external library

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to delete a cookie using the `js-cookie` library.

Note that this cookie is not created by me. Is by another team and 
can't be changing this cookie in any manner.

But the cookie remains even after attempting to delete.

Could I please know what I am doing wrong?

These are the details of the cookie.

```
name: my_cookie
value: uligasdf67gdjfkb
Domain: .mycompany.com 
Path: /
Expires / Max-Age: 2021-09-15T21:39:37:757Z  
Size  59 
HttpOnly: Has a tick which I believe indicates yes. 
SameSite: Lax 
SameParty: (Empty)
Priority: Medium
```

This cookie is set to expire in 10 minutes after being set but depending on certain logic, I want to just delete it before the expiry.

This is how I am trying to delete it which no effect, cookie not deleted.

Using `js-cookie` package.

Importing in my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
  "js-cookie": "^2.2.0"
},
```

Logic to delete.

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
Cookies.remove('my_cookie', { path: '/', domain: '.mycompany.com' });
```

Is there a way around this to delete it?

Edit:

Tried what is suggested in this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64723114/delete-httponly-cookies-express) to set cookie with empty value to essentially delete cookie.

```
Cookies.set('my_cookie', '');
```

But I end up with 2 cookies. The difference being the domain.

The existing cookie which is still not deleted.

```
name       value          domain
my_cookie  asdfasdfasfd   .mycompany.com
```

Cookie getting duplicated instead of overriding

```
name       value          domain
my_cookie                 qwww.mycompany.com
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete the cookie on the same URL as where you set it?

Comment: @Dominik Yes that is correct.

Comment: Perhaps try `domain: 'mycompany.com'` instead of `domain: '.mycompany.com'` (setting and deleting)

Comment: @Dominik Tried that with and without the dot. Same outcome. Also tried another suggestion to create new cookie to override the existing one to essentially delete. Doesn't work either. Updated about this on the question above.

Comment: I mean I would manually delete the current cookie and then try again without the dot